# How to show payment form on node form preview in Drupal 7?

Tags: commerce

I have make a content type, I have make compulsory to preview node before saving, now what I need when user click on the preview button, he can review his information which he wrote in the form and then there should be payment form, if the payment is successful, node will be saved else not.

Answer (score 0):

Try out [Pay-per-node](http://drupal.org/project/paypernode) module.

> It can be used as standalone module or as an e-commerce plug-in. In
>   the second case paypernode can be integrated with Ubercart, providing
>   a new "product feature" which will allow, upon product purchase, to
>   create a number of nodes.